# Api to fetch recoverable contents for calendar in outlook

Tags: python, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

When we delete an item, it can be found in Deleted folder. And if we delete that item from Deleted folder then it goes in recoverable items in outlook.(this is true for mails,contacts and calendars)

So I can access the recoverable mails using `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/messages`
and contacts using `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/contactfolders/RecoverableItemsDeletions/contacts`.

Now I can't access my calendar event that has been deleted from Deleted folder. I am trying to use this Api -

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendars/RecoverableItemsDeletions/events
```

I can still see my calendar event in recoverable folder but can't access using api.

Comment: Have you checked this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/policy-and-compliance/recoverable-items-folder/recoverable-items-folder?view=exchserver-2019 . I noticed that the Calendar Logging,“this subfolder contains calendar changes that occur within a mailbox. This folder isn't available to users”.

Comment: Yes. for query 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders//{id of calendar logging}/messages', it returns 200 but doesn't give any result(deleted events are still in recoverable folder).
And if we replace messages with events then it gives 400 error.
You can test the queries here https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: I'm afraid you can't get the datas for calendar.